# Given the function `decode`, how can I do the inverse and write a function to `encode`?

Tags: c, encoding, bit-manipulation

Basically, I have a function called encode, and I want to do the opposite of this and basically encode into a hexadecimal value. Also, it may be worth mentioning that I'm writing in C.

```
void decode(somestruct *thing, int instr) {
    thing->instrNum = (instr & 0xF000) >> 12;
    thing->reg1     = (instr & 0xF00 ) >>  8;
    thing->reg2     = (instr & 0xF0  ) >>  4;
    thing->reg3     = (instr & 0xF   );
    thing->imm      = (instr & 0xFF  );
}
```

Is there any way I can do this, preferably the smaller the better :) I was thinking of laying it out like this:

```
int encode(int instrNum, int reg1, int reg2, int reg3, int imm) {
    // do conversion to base 2 then base 16
    return the_base_16_conversion;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like it to return a value such as 0x6100.

Please tell me if this doesn't make sense, I'm not too great at writing questions :(

Comment: If you have `imm`, `reg2` and `reg3` are unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, it's for a virtual machine, so I can give the instructions of: `instrNum, reg 1, reg 2, reg 3` or `instrNum reg1, imm` or in other words, `add stored_here, value_a, value_b`, or `set stored_here, value_to_set`

Comment: I want an easy way to encode and decode instructions for the VM :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm slow, but where are `instrNum`, `reg1`, etc. declared and what do they mean? Arethey global variables? And why does decode not return an `int`?

Comment: Oh, my bad, decode should return void. And I've defined the values in decode in a struct, I just wrote the code in as opposed to copying and pasting it from my source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `imm`, `reg2` and `reg3` are unnecessary. Use left shifting to "undo" right shifting. Use bitwise "OR" to combine the parts. The whole function would look like this:

```
return ((instrNum  & 0xF) << 12) | ((reg1 & 0xF) << 8) | imm;
```

If only one of `imm` or {`reg2`, `reg3`} pair could be specified, you could do this preparatory step before the `return` statement:

```
if (!imm) imm = ((reg2 & 0xF) << 8) | (reg3 & 0xF);
```

Comment: I don't think this is working, basically I have an instruction set like `set r0 #100`, which is in hex `0x1064`, which is in binary `0b1000001100100`. So basically I want to pass the function these integers, and convert them to the hex value 0x1064, if that makes sense?

Comment: set = 1, r0 = 0, 100 = 100, convert that to the hexadecimal value 0x1064? (Assuming that bits 15-12 is 1(set), 11-8 is 0(reg), bits 7 - 0 is the immediate value)

Comment: @freefouran Yes, that is what you are going to get ([link to a demo](http://ideone.com/56fGfZ)).

Comment: OHHH okay, great, didn't realize I was formatting it as a decimal <3